# imap_createmailbox и кириллица

Tags: php, imap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью функции imap_createmailbox() создать папку с русскими буквами. Нашел пример, где говорится, что надо кириллицу кодировать функцией imap_utf7_encode(), но она не помогает - создает ужасные иероглифы. Уверен, что есть простое решение.

Comment: Я когда создавал папку на сервере, для имени использовал iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251",  $name);
Так как сервер на диску windows а сам файл использует кодировку UTF-8.

Comment: создало папку 쿰쇠